# Checking if two trigonometric expressions are equal

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

Say I have two trigonometric expressions which are a bit complicated. Is there a quick way to check if they reduce to the same thing (that they are equal) using Mathematica?

I was solving this: $y'' + y = \cos 4x,$ $y(0) = 6, y'(0) = 11$ using Laplace transformation technique, and I get this: $y = \frac{-1}{15}\cos(4x) + \left(\frac{1}{15} + 6\right) \cos(x) + 11 \sin(x)$.
I wanted to check if my answer is correct and Mathematica gave me this:

```
1/30 (182 Cos[x] - 5 Cos[x] Cos[3 x] + 3 Cos[x] Cos[5 x]
      + 330 Sin[x] + 5 Sin[x] Sin[3 x] + 3 Sin[x] Sin[5 x])
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullSimplify.html):

```
FullSimplify[Sin[x] == Tan[x] Cos[x]]
```

This returns `True` if `Sin[x] == Tan[x] Cos[x]` (which it does).

Please note that `==` ([`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html)) should be used instead of a single equal sign ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html)). More complicated trig identities can be difficult to reason about. *Mathematica* may not be able to properly determine whether they are true or not. You can still ask for *Mathematica*'s opinion in these cases however.

If the identity is very difficult, you may consider using [`PossibleZeroQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) :

```
PossibleZeroQ[Sin[x] - Tan[x] Cos[x]]
```

Instead of equating the left hand side with the right hand side, subtract them. Then give these expression to `PossibleZeroQ`.  `PossibleZeroQ` tests whether it is likely that a given expression is equal to 0.

If you believe the identity is false but would like an example, you can get this using [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindInstance.html). Here, we ask *Mathematica* to find an instance where `Sin[x]` does not  equal (`!=`) `Tan[x] Cos[x]`:

```
FindInstance[Sin[x] != Tan[x] Cos[x], x]
```

*Mathematica* doesn't return any answer. This makes sense because both sides are equal.

Comment: Great!! FullySimplify worked just well. And my answer is correct :D Thank you a lot!

Comment: If `FindInstance[expr1[x] != expr2[x], x]` doesn't yields any answer it doesn't mean that `expr1[x] == expr2[x]` !!!!!

Comment: Oh I most certainly didn't mean to imply that. It's simply just useful in these kinds of cases. Like PossibleZeroQ, its results don't really guarantee anything.

Comment: Try `Sin[x] == Tan[x] Cos[x]`  without `FullSimplify`, it returns `True` because of built-in rewrite rules, so your example is completely inadequate.

Comment: `Sin[x] === Tan[x] Cos[x]` yields `True`, while `Sin[x] != Tan[x] Cos[x]` returns `False`, also `Sin[x] - Tan[x] Cos[x]` yields `0`.  No need neither for `PossibleZeroQ`, `FindInstance`, nor `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Yes. I get it. The purpose of explaining it this way was to present a general method instead of presenting 6 different cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

There is no best general way to check if any two trigonometric expressions are equal. One can use `TrigReduce`, `TrigExpand`, `TrigFactor`, `TrigToExp`, `Together` and `Apart` (especially with the `Trig->True` option), `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, etc. All these functions have their advantages and we discuss some of them.  For more complicated examples when using `Simplify` and  `FullSimplify` we can encounter problems with timings and/or memory allocation, we give an appropriate example later.

In case of your example I recommend to evaluate `TrigReduce` on the difference of the both expressions.

Sometimes you needn't use any simplifications, and quite inevident expressions are simplified automatically by built-in rewrite rules.

First we consider a few examples where no *Mathematica* functions are needed.

**ex 1.**

$$\sum_{\small{k = 1}}^{\small{k = m-1}} \;\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(\frac{k\; \pi}{m})} = \frac{m^{2} -1}{3} $$

```
Sum[ 1/Sin[ k Pi/m]^2, {k, 1, m - 1}]
```

> ```
> 1/3 (-1 + m^2)
> ```

if we set e.g. `m = 21`, the above doesn't simplify and we need e.g. `FullSimplify`

```
m = 21;
FullSimplify @ Sum[ 1/Sin[ k Pi/m]^2, {k, 1, m - 1}]
```

> ```
> 440/3
> ```

The larger one sets `m`, the more time it takes.

Here is another example where we need no simplifications and the result is obtained with help of built-in rewrite rules :

**ex 2.**

$$\sum_{\small{k = 0}}^{\small{k = m-1}} \; \cos(a + k b) = \frac{\sin(\frac{n b}{2})}{\sin(\frac{b}{2})} \cos(\frac{2 a+(n-1) b}{2})$$

```
(Sum[ Cos[ a + k b], {k, 0, m - 1}] - 
      Sin[ (m b)/2]/Sin[ b/2]  Cos[ (2 a + (m - 1) b)/2]) /. m -> 137
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

but if we make no substitution we'll need e.g. `Simplify`

```
Simplify[ (Sum[ Cos[ a + k b], {k, 0, m - 1}] - 
                Sin[ (m b)/2]/Sin[ b/2]  Cos[ (2 a + (m - 1) b)/2]) ]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

It works even if we add the option `Simplify[ expr, Trig -> False]`.

**ex 3.**

$$\sum_{\small{k = 0}}^{\small{k = n-2}} \; \tan(\frac{\pi}{2^{n - k}}) = \cot(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}})$$

Here we define e.g.

```
f[n_] := Sum[2^k Tan[Pi/2^(n - k)], {k, 0, n - 2}] - Cot[Pi/2^n]
```

In this case the following functions work equally well if we set e.g. `n == 15` :

```
Together[ f[n], Trig -> True] == Simplify[ f[n]] == TrigReduce[ f[n]] == 0
```

> ```
> True
> ```

however for larger `n` we can easily see advantages of various approaches, e.g. for `n == 21` we observe that `Together[ expr, Trig->True]` is the best, while `Simplify` cannot tackle such an expression :

```
TrigReduce[ f[21]] // AbsoluteTiming
Together[f[21], Trig -> True] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.1404000, 0}
> {0.0312000, 0}
> ```

while

```
Simplify[f[21]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

returns

[image]

If we evaluate e.g. `f[n]`, where we haven't assigned to `n` any value, we get `ComplexInfinity`.

At last we consider two simple examples :

**ex 4.**

```
expr1 = -1 + 50 Cos[x]^2 - 400 Cos[x]^4 + 1120 Cos[x]^6 - 1280 Cos[x]^8;
expr2 = -512 Cos[x]^10 + Cos[10 x];
```

In this case one can use

```
TrigReduce[ expr1 - expr2]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

as well as one of these

```
Together[ expr1 - expr2, Trig -> True]
```

or

```
Apart[ expr1 - expr2, Trig -> True]
```

Let's consider your example :

**ex 5.**

```
exprA =        - 1/15 Cos[4 x] + (1/15 + 6) Cos[x] + 11 Sin[x];
exprB =   1/30 (  182 Cos[x] - 5 Cos[x] Cos[3 x] + 3 Cos[x] Cos[5 x] + 330 Sin[x] 
              + 5 Sin[x] Sin[3 x] + 3 Sin[x] Sin[5 x] );
```

compare various ways (`TrigReduce` and `TrigExpand` are optimal here) :

```
TrigReduce[exprA - exprB] // AbsoluteTiming
TrigExpand[exprA - exprB] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0., 0}
> {0., 0}
> ```

but `FullSimplify` and `TrigFactor` also work, though are a bit slower :

```
TrigFactor[exprA - exprB] // AbsoluteTiming
FullSimplify[exprA - exprB] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0156000, 0} 
> {0.0312000, 0}
> ```

Thus using `TrigReduce` seems to be more appropriate for this type of trigonometric expressions. We can observe that timing for is a multiple of `0.0156000` for `TrigFactor` and `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Fantastic! This also worked. Thank you!

Comment: @stupidity Note that is an appropriate approach to simplify purely trigonemetric expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here is another approach (that I would use intuitively, if I didn't know the other functions existed):

```
expr1 = -1 + 50 Cos[x]^2 - 400 Cos[x]^4 + 1120 Cos[x]^6 - 1280 Cos[x]^8;
expr2 = -512 Cos[x]^10 + Cos[10 x];

Integrate[(expr1 - expr2)^2, {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

> ```
>  0
> ```

Comment: Sin[x]*Exp[-x^2] - x*Cos[x]*Exp[-x^2]

Comment: @acl point noted - see edit.

Comment: I'd use `Abs` but +1 this is how I think too (not sure that's good, but...)

Comment: @acl `Abs` does not return an analytical solution (in the 10 min I left it to run) for your example. This is why I used `^2`

Comment: I'd also do that numerically with `NIntegrate` to start with (and `Quiet` it to avoid complaints if it is zero). I don't trust mathematica to work reliably with analytical expressions (as in, I don't trust it to finish or choose the branches I want etc), so I almost never use it for that.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use `PossibleZeroQ`

   ```
   expr1 = -1/15 Cos[4 x] + (1/15 + 6) Cos[x] + 11 Sin[x];
   expr2 = 1/30 (182 Cos[x] - 5 Cos[x] Cos[3 x] + 3 Cos[x] Cos[5 x] + 
        330 Sin[x] + 5 Sin[x] Sin[3 x] + 3 Sin[x] Sin[5 x]);    
   PossibleZeroQ[expr1 - expr2]

   (* Out= True *)
   ```
2. Use *Mathematica's* `InputForm` for showing examples. Wastes much less time for others who later work with them. Took me three tries to get all the typos out of my transcription of `expr1`.