# Checking if two expresssions are equal in mathematica fails

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to see if two expressions are equal. I have tried all of the methods [outlined in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/checking-if-two-trigonometric-expressions-are-equal) but none seem to work.

I have two expressions, `part1` and `part2`:

```
\[CapitalSigma] = r^2 + a^2*Cos[theta]^2;
\[CapitalDelta] = r^2 - 2*r + a^2;
part1 = (-((3 a^2 r)/2) + r^3 -3/2 a^2 r Cos[2 theta])/((a^2 + (-2 + r) r) (r^2 +a^2 Cos[theta]^2)^2);
part2 = (r*(r^2 - 3*a*Cos[theta]^2))/(\[CapitalSigma]^2*\[CapitalDelta]);
```

These two expressions are equal and so I expect `FullSimplify[part1 == part2]` to return `True`, but it does not.

Any ideas?

Comment: They're not equal. Consider `{a -> -2, r -> 1, theta -> -1}` or `{a -> 2, theta -> 0, r -> 1}`

Comment: The two expressions **are** equal when typo is fixed in `part1 = (-((3 a r)/2) + r^3 - 
     3/2 a r Cos[2 theta])/((a^2 + (-2 + r) r) (r^2 + a^2 Cos[theta]^2)^2);` That is, the two `a^2` in the numerator should be replaced with `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try giving some numerical values to `r`, `a` and `theta`,

```
r = 10; a = 10; theta = 10;

\[CapitalSigma] = r^2 + a^2*Cos[theta]^2;
\[CapitalDelta] = r^2 - 2*r + a^2;

 part1 = (-((3 a^2 r)/2) + r^3 - 3/2 a^2 r Cos[
       2 theta])/((a^2 + (-2 + r) r) (r^2 + a^2 Cos[theta]^2)^2) //Simplify
```

> -((1 + 3 Cos[20])/(900 (3 + Cos[20])^2))

```
part2 = (r*(r^2 - 3*a*Cos[theta]^2))/(\[CapitalSigma]^2*\[CapitalDelta]) //Simplify
```

> (17 - 3 Cos[20])/(9000 (3 + Cos[20])^2)

```
FullSimplify[part1 == part2]
```

> False

So your two expressions are not equal